# Is it possible to hide or move default macOS apps?

Tags: finder, applications, filesystem

I am trying to cleanup/organize my applications folder which is difficult because I can't move most of the apps (Technically I can move them but a copy is locked in the same position).

Is there any way to hide the .app files of apps I don't want to see or some way to force them to move so I can organize the Applications folder?

Most of the methods I have seen involve deleting the apps but I do not want to do that.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2):

Which applications are you having trouble moving? I tried a few: `Photo Booth`, `Calendar` and `System Preferences`.  They all moved to the new location without any issues, and also functioned after the move.

---

You can hide files fairly easily in the Terminal.app:

```
sudo chflags hidden "/Applications/Chess.app"
```

to unhide:

```
sudo chflags nohidden "/Applications/Chess.app"
```

- You'll need to enter admin password after entering either one of these commands
- You can drag a file to the Terminal window to get the file path. It doesn't add the double quotes around the file path, but that should not be necessary in this case. If it doesn't appear to be working, you may wanna try adding the double quotes.

---

You don't need to see the file to unhide it, but it does help so you can easily copy the path and you don't need to remember which files are hidden. Seeing hidden files in Finder is a little less intuitive though...

If you want to see all hidden files in the system, there are applications where this is a built in feature: [TotalFinder](https://totalfinder.binaryage.com/), [XtraFinder](https://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/), [Path Finder](https://cocoatech.com/), [Commander One](https://mac.eltima.com/file-manager.html)...but you can show them in Finder as well, using the Terminal.app:

Should be noted that both of these commands here will close all finder windows

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall -KILL Finder
```

And to hide all hidden files:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall -KILL Finder
```

Comment: I realized it might not be obvious, so I thought I should also mention that chflags takes multiple files at once too. So you could do like `sudo chflags hidden /Applications/Dashboard.app /Applications/DVD\ Player.app /Applications/Contacts.app /Applications/Chess.app /Applications/Calculator.app`. And you can feed multiple file paths by dragging multiple files to the Terminal window.

Comment: It won't let me do the sudo chflags on Chess.app. After entraining my password it says "Operation not permitted"

Comment: @CalebK does it appear to be the only application that isn't letting you do it? I don't have a proper answer to give you right now, other than... You should be able to hide it. I did try it myself on a Mac with El Capitan with SIP disabled, but I don't think that should make a difference. I'll try it again a bit later.

Comment: Based on [this article from apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899), I'm going to assume Chess app is not the only app you can't hide. It says `System Integrity Protection includes protection for these parts of the system: Apps that are pre-installed with OS X `. Based on this... The moving and/or hiding issue you are having is because of SIP. If you really wish to hide them, you could disable SIP, hide apps and then enable SIP again. You can google info on how to disable SIP. It's not very complicated.