# How to update Dock preview to Applications folder after hiding apps with chflags

Tags: finder, macos, dock

I am using `chflags hidden` method to hide apps in `/Applications` folder.

It immediately hides the application in *Finder*, but when I click on the *Applications* folder in *Dock* ([image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNbhu.png)), I can still see the hidden applications there, until I restart the computer.

So the question is: **Is it possible to also update the visibility of the application in the *Dock* preview to *Applications* folder without restaring the computer?**

[image]

Comment: You actually shouldn't be needed to kill finder after setting chflags. My best guess is that you are running El Capitan or anything after that. [I recently answered a question where OP was trying to do the same thing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/290399/126929). OP was pretty tight lipped when it came to giving additional info, but in my last comment to my own answer I came to the realization that it likely worked for me because I've disabled SIP. I'm pretty sure this is the reason it's not working for you  as well.

Comment: @Joonas: SIP is disabled. Running Sierra. Basically It works partially without restarting computer - if I click on `Dock -> Applications -> Open in Finder`, then even without restarting the app folder is hidden. However, it's not hidden right in `Dock->Applications`, until I restart.

Comment: These two paths... I don't quite understand what they are. Shouldn't both open in Finder regardless?

Comment: I've added a stab at guessing your `spctl --status` and OS version - please correct @pablo. I'll delete our other comments since we're beyond them now. I'm curious as to the real nut to be cracked here now that SIP is implicated.

Comment: I've updated my question to depict 2 paths.

Comment: I would have to test it to see what my mac, but I wouldn't be surprised if this dock `applications alias` or what ever it is didn't honor chflags... That's what it seems like.

Comment: @Joonas: why it honors after restart? I would think there is some cache, which need to be reset.

Comment: Oh (forgot about that). Well in that case I'd guess it updates itself differently... It's independent from Finder, which also brought me to realize.... in that case, you should probably do `killall -kill Dock`.

Comment: If you blur almost everything, the two screenshots are useless without mentioning which folders/apps are/should be hidden.

Comment: @Pablo, I edited the question pretty heavy handedly... (Assuming it gets approved) so be sure to edit it if you feel It's wrong.

Comment: @klanomath: the problem applies to all non-built-in apps that I installed.

Comment: @Joonas: actually killing Dock helps. Is it graceful method?

Comment: @Pablo, I'm not sure what that means in this context. It's forces Dock to close and then it gets restored. I don't think there are any processes Dock has that this could disrupt. If you add or remove a dock item and immediately run killall, Dock won't forget it. I was reading doc for [killall](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/killall.1.html) to find out more about how it kills a processs, but it doesn't really clarify. My understanding is that if you kill Finder this way, you better make sure you don't have any file transfer going on...

Comment: ...but that is Finder. Either way, I added another way for closing Dock in my answer. Just know that you can chain the killall with the chflags: `sudo chflags hidden /Applications/Dictionary.app; killall Dock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it and doing `killall Dock` in Terminal.app does the job.

> This specific *killall* command will essentially restart Dock and therefore the *Applications* folder preview gets updated as well.

---

---

Alternatively you can open `/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app` search for `Dock`, select it and click the X in the top left corner of the window.